# How to select from Postgresql's timestamp type by a special format with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

For example, the created_at value is `2014-12-25 01:02:03`, I want to get all the data which created_at like `2014-12` from database.

If SQLite, the code like this:

```
Model.where("created_at like ?", '2014-12' + "%")
```

But when PostgreSQL, how to do?

---

## Addition

From the log, I found:

```
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Blog Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "blogs".* FROM "blogs" WHERE (created_at like '2014-12%')  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 58ms
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown
```

Comment: I used Model.where("created like ?" "2014-12%") for PostgreSQL with no problem. Not sure if it answers your question though since it looks awfully similar.

Comment: @voidwalker But that doesn't work for me. By the way, I am using Heroku and I have added some error logs above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres to get all data which `created_at` like `2014-12` you can use [`Postgres#date_part()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
.where("date_part('year', created_at) = ? and date_part('month', created_at) = ?", '2014' , '12')
```

This query return all records where years `created_at` equal `2014` and month equal `12`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe it can fix the problem about PostgreSQL, but I want to know isn't there a common way to deal with both SQLite and PostgreSQL?

Comment: @j-zhang sorry but i cant understand what you mean.

Comment: It doesn't matter:) I have fixed it by database adapter check way. I am using Rails. My development environment is using SQLite and production environment is using PostgreSQL.